# DirichletTransform gives incorrect result

Tags: bugs, number-theory

**Bug introduced in 13.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0 or later.**

---

Input 1:

```
DirichletConvolve[MoebiusMu[m], MangoldtLambda[m]/m, m, n];
DirichletTransform[%, n, s]

(* -(Zeta'[1+s]/(Zeta[s] Zeta[1+s])) *)
```

Input 2:

```
DirichletConvolve[MoebiusMu[m], MangoldtLambda[m]/m, m, 2 n];
DirichletTransform[%, n, s]

(* 0 *)
```

Why does `DirichletTransform` return this wrong result in the second case? I use Mathematica 13.0.

UPDATE:

There are even more issues with `DirichletTransform`:

```
DirichletTransform[
 DirichletConvolve[Log[m] MoebiusMu[m], Mod[m, 2], m, n], n, s]

(* 2^(-s) (-1 + 2^s) $Failed Zeta[s] *)
```

The correct result should be:

```
2^(-s) (-1 + 2^s) Zeta'[s]/Zeta[s]
```

Comment: Given Input2, DirichletTransform[%, 2*n, s] gives the original answer.

Comment: @James Cunnane: `DirichletTransform[%, 2*n, s]` has no sense, second argument of `DirichletTransform` should be a variable with respect to which the transform should be computed. So it is another strange behavior of `DirichletTransform`.

Comment: Please [report this to Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback) if you haven't already done so.

Comment: I updated my OP with another error. Not sure I will have time to fill any report.