# Repeated DirichletConvolve of MangoldtLambda and MoebiusMu

Tags: number-theory

There is a **bug** in `DirichletConvolve`.

These two codes are same except that in first one `MoebiusMu` is used in another `MangoldtLambda`.

This works as expected, first line return unevaluated output, since `n3` is unknown, second line after replacing `n3` with `12` return correct result `-9`:

```
Clear[n1,n2,n3]
DirichletConvolve[
 DirichletConvolve[MoebiusMu[n1], MoebiusMu[n1], n1, n2], 
 MoebiusMu[n2], n2, n3]
DirichletConvolve[
 DirichletConvolve[MoebiusMu[n1], MoebiusMu[n1], n1, n2], 
 MoebiusMu[n2], n2, 12]

(* DirichletConvolve[
 DirichletConvolve[MoebiusMu[n1], MoebiusMu[n1], n1, n2], 
 MoebiusMu[n2], n2, n3] *)
(* -9 *)
```

But this is bugged, first line return `0`, even though `n3` is unknown, second line after replacing `n3` with `12` return correct result `3 Log[2]^2 Log[3]`:

```
Clear[n1,n2,n3]
DirichletConvolve[
 DirichletConvolve[MangoldtLambda[n1], MangoldtLambda[n1], n1, n2], 
 MangoldtLambda[n2], n2, n3]
DirichletConvolve[
 DirichletConvolve[MangoldtLambda[n1], MangoldtLambda[n1], n1, n2], 
 MangoldtLambda[n2], n2, 12]

(* 0 *)
(* 3 Log[2]^2 Log[3] *)
```

I am really frustrated with Mathematica 13. Here another example of bugs in [DirichletTransform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269736/dirichlettransform-gives-incorrect-result).

Comment: Please do not use the bugs tag for new questions: it is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug.

Comment: Then there should be two tags - one `bugs` when OP thinks it is a bug and one `confirmed-bugs` when community confirms it is a bug. And the tag `confirmed-bugs` can be forbidden to choose straight at writing the question.

Comment: You are welcome to make that case in the MMA.Meta site, but that's not what we currently have. The usage of bugs is pretty clearly explained in [its tag wiki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs). I personally see no point in having a tag for a "potential bug", if the behavior is not confirmed to be one.

Comment: But then you do not have the reason to search for a potential bug. If I did not state it is a bug in Mathematica, someone could post an answer with his own Dirichlet convolution function that would fulfill my requirements and I would accept the answer without even revealing there is bug in Mathematica.

Comment: Here is how I understand the process: in your question, you describe the puzzling behavior and SAY that you think you found a bug, with examples of actual output, and what you think should be the correct output instead, and why. People will then either confirm that it is a bug, or show you why it is not. If the behavior is confirmed to be a bug, then you or somebody else can add the bugs tag and the standard bugs header. The fact that the behavior is a bug is then not only very evident, but also much better documented.